# Display variable with auto-increment

Tags: php, forms, variables, auto-increment

I have a form that records various fields with a variable name in autoincrement.
when I save my my form variables looks like

```
<form>
<?php 
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($variables as $var ) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="txt$i" value="$var->name" />';
        $i ++;
    }
?>
</form>
```

And my question is how to display the value of the input field, i make that, but not working

```
<?php 
    foreach ($variables as $var) {
        echo $var->txt$i;
        $i ++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of bugs in both of your scripts. Here they are fixed.

```
<form>
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach ($variables as $var ) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="txt' . $i . '" value="' . $var->name . '" />';
    $i++;
}
?>
</form> 
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach ($variables as $var) {
    echo $var->{"txt" . $i};
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[In PHP, single-quoted strings do not allow for variable interpolation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Try:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="txt' . $i . '" value="' . $var->name . '" />';
```

Comment: Hello Jack, thanks for your answer, but how to display it after save with for each function ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  How to display what after what?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using single quotes:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="txt$i" value="$var->name" />';
```

and inside single quotes variable interpolation does not happen.

Instead use:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="txt'.$i.'" value="'.$var->name.'" />';
```

Comment: Hello Codeaddict, thanks for your answer, but how to display it after save with for each function ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
<form>
<?php 
  $variables = array("red","yellow","blue","orange","green");
  $i = 1;

 foreach ($variables as $var ) {
     $name = "txt".$i;
     echo "<input type='text' name='".$name."' value='".$var."' />";
     $i++;
 } ?>
</form>
```

You need to put variables in double quotes, i thought it would be easier to create a name variable and concatenate the incremented value on to the end of it

Answer (score -1):

Can't get what you want from your question.
May be just

```
echo $txt.$i;
```

?

Comment: Hello Col. Shrapnel,
thanks for you answer, but it display "1" and no my var

Comment: Hello Tomaw, thanks for your comment, but you have to ask a sensible question to get a right answer.